# Weird behavior in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this part in a user profile template:

```
    <p>{{ user.get_username }} = {{ profile.username  }} </p>

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}          
       {% if user.get_username != profile.username   %}
            This is the profile of another user             
       {% else%}
            This is your profile
     {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
```

Which generates this seemingly absurd output:

```
bob = bob
This is the profile of another user
```

Why is it so and how to fix it?

UPDATE: 
Here is the UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username =  models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    canpost=models.BooleanField(default=True)


    User.profile = property(lambda u:UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=u)[0])
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a space at the end or beginning of either of the strings?

Comment: Well `-{{ user.get_username }},{{ profile.username  }}-` also gives:  `-bob,bob-`

Comment: Can you show us what your models.py looks like? Just the User model (if extended) and UserProfile model will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is comparing the user `username` (string) against the profile `username` (which is an object). You can use `profile.username.username` instead of `profile.username`, but the proper convention (which is also more logical), is to rename your Profile model's `username` field to `user`, and access the name via `profile.user.username`.

Comment: Well, I have not defined a `def get_username(self):`.  I'm using the native: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_username

Comment: In that case, put up your profile models.py in your original post. I have a feeling that it's still a variation of the issue I mentioned above.

Comment: Just added the model.

Comment: ah I figured it out. It should be `{% if user.get_username != profile.username.username %}`. Thanks for your hint. mention this and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Great! like I thought it was a variation of my previous answer. I edited my answer again to show you a better approach - naming convention is really important for reasons like this. :)

Comment: Right, just renamed the field. The naming was admittedly it so lame!